# ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT inside a STORED procedure in postgreSQL 11 and the below code is failing to compile?

Tags: postgresql

Upgrading to postgresSQL 11, the below stored procedure is failing to compile.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE savePointProc(startOrRollbak INTEGER, inVar VARCHAR) 
as $$
DECLARE
BEGIN   
    IF startOrRollbak = 0 THEN
       SAVEPOINT inVar;
     ELSE
       ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT inVar ;
     END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

## in postgreSQL 11

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"
LINE 8:      ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT inVar ;
                      ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 180

Can someone point me what is incorrect in the above which makes the procedure compilation fail ?

Have removed the ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"

```
create or replace PROCEDURE savePointProc(startOrRollbak INTEGER, inVar 
VARCHAR) as $$
DECLARE
BEGIN   
   IF startOrRollbak = 0 THEN
      SAVEPOINT inVar;
   ELSE
      ROLLBACK TO inVar ;
   END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

error :
LINE 8:      ROLLBACK TO inVar ;
                      ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 180
```

Comment: Check if this helps : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125440/if-con-extending-sql-en-postgresql-stored-procedure#125475

Comment: Thanks, i believe the error is more related to ROLLBACK TO*

Comment: `The SQL standard specifies that the key word SAVEPOINT is mandatory, but PostgreSQL and Oracle allow it to be omitted`

Ref : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-rollback-to.html

Comment: Have tried omitting SAVEPOINT keyword, but its the same error on TO

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"
LINE 8:      ROLLBACK TO inVar ;
                      ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 180

Comment: Can you post your error in formatted code. It's not quite clear from question where the '^' is pointing.

Comment: have updated the edit with proper error post removing the SAVEPOINT keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that Pl/pgSQL syntax accepts SAVEPOINT ... but not ROLLBACK TO ... syntax.

You can try to use dynamic SQL: it is compiled without error but fails at execution time (tested with PG 11.7):

```
drop table t;
DROP TABLE
create table t(x int);
CREATE TABLE
create or replace procedure tsp(inVar VARCHAR)
as $$
BEGIN   
      SAVEPOINT inVar;
      insert into t values(1);  
      EXECUTE "ROLLBACK TO $1" USING inVar;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE PROCEDURE
There is no previous error.
call tsp('sp1');
psql:tsp.sql:13: ERROR:  unsupported transaction command in PL/pgSQL
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function tsp(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
psql:tsp.sql:14: ERROR:  0A000: unsupported transaction command in PL/pgSQL
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function tsp(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
LOCATION:  exec_stmt_execsql, pl_exec.c:4194
select * from t;
 x 
---
(0 rows)
```

Looks like that the right way to use SAVEPOINT in Pl/pgSQL is BEGIN/END block with EXCEPTION clause.